# Different characters skins, In app purchases best practices

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I am making a 2d game in unity where users will be able to unlock new skins in game that will consist of new animations as well. The way I was originally going to go about this is by having the different Sprites named sprite_01 sprite_02 etc and when a player unlocks a Sprite it adds the index number of that Sprite to their unlocks column in the database. This was if player x unlocks 1 and 2, 1,2 would be added to the database. This way I can tell which Sprites were unlocked by the user. I would then attach the appropriate animation controller to the player prefab when the user chooses a skin.

This is my mediocre attempt at trying to solve this but I am new to this type of integration. I was looking to see if anyone here could point me in the right direction as the best to to do this.

Comment: nothing wrong with that way of doing it, go ahead